# Could you please suggest physics textbooks that discuss object velocity and image velocity pertaining to spherical and plane mirrors?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, reflection, geometric-optics, education

I have seen texts such as Zemansky's University Physics or Halliday Resnick's Physics (fundamentals and the older edition) etc. do not contain discussions on object velocity, image velocity (and their relation) in geometrical optics unit. So, I request for the books that discuss these topics along with problems (solved and exercises).

Comment: what do you mean by “image velocity”?

Comment: The relative velocity of image with respect to object or ground or with respect to a moving mirror when the object moves in front of mirror.

Comment: well… you just gave 3 definitions.  which one applies to your question?

Comment: All three, I mean, I need text that discusses all those.